# An exception occurred processing JSP page /AddMemberAction.jsp at line 41

Tags: java

I am getting a runtime error . It says that there is null pointer exception in loggermanager.java.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /AddMemberAction.jsp at line 41

```
38:      }
39:      catch(Exception e)
40:      { 
41:        LoggerManager.writeLogWarning(e);
42:      }
43:      response.sendRedirect("ViewProjectMembers.jsp");
44:     %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.dts.core.util.LoggerManager.writeLogWarning(LoggerManager.java:58)
    org.apache.jsp.AddMemberAction_jsp._jspService(AddMemberAction_jsp.java:135)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.jal
```

Loggermanager.java

```
package com.dts.core.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class LoggerManager {
  public static Logger logger;

  public LoggerManager() {}

  public Logger getLogger(String file) {
    String dir = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("/"));
    System.out.println("-----dir----" + dir);
    logger = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
    try {
      File f = new File(dir);
      boolean success = f.exists();

      if (!success) {
        success = f.mkdir();
      }
      LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
      FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(file, true);
      logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggerManager");
      logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
      lm.addLogger(logger);
      logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
      fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
      logger.addHandler(fh);

    } catch (Exception e) {

      logger.log(Level.INFO, e.toString(), e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
    return logger;
  }

  public static void writeLogInfo(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, e.toString(), e.fillInStackTrace());
  }

  public static void writeLogSevere(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e.fillInStackTrace());
  }

  public static void writeLogWarning(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.toString(), e.fillInStackTrace());
  }

  public static void writeLogInfo(String info) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, info);
  }

  public static void writeLogSevere(String severe) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, severe);
  }

  public static void writeLogWarning(String warning) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, warning);
  }
}
```

Below is the souce code where LoggerManager.writeLogWarning(3); is present

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.dts.core.dao.*,com.dts.core.model.*,com.dts.core.util.*,com.dts.btisqr.model.*,com.dts.btisqr.dao.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,com.dts.dae.dao.*,com.dts.dae.model.*"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">

    <title>My JSP 'AddMemberAction.jsp' starting page</title>

    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    -->

  </head>

  <body>
   <%
     try
     {
        int projectid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("projectid"));
        String member = request.getParameter("member");   
        Project aProject = new Project();
        aProject.setProjectID(projectid);
        aProject.setAssignedTo(member);

        new ProjectsDAO().assignProject(aProject);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     { 
       LoggerManager.writeLogWarning(e);
     }
     response.sendRedirect("ViewProjectMembers.jsp");
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could not find this line  LoggerManager.writeLogWarning(e); in your source code,I think you are missing some codes here

Answer (score 0):

If the `NullPointerException` is thrown in line 58 of `LoggerManager` class it looks like `logger` variable is not initialized properly.
I suggest to add getLogger() method that will do something like this

```
private static Logger getLogger() {
    if (logger == null) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggerManager");
    }
    return logger;
}
```

And after that change your `writeLogWarning` method to something like that

```
public static void writeLogWarning(String warning) {
    getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, warning);
}
```

Generally I think that you should perform some refactoring on `LoggerManager` class. As I can see all `writeLogX()` methods are static but they uses `logger` variable which is clearly non-static variable. 
What's more `logger` is initialized only in one public method

```
public Logger getLogger(String file)
```

which is an instance method. 
You should make a decision if `LoggerManager` is an util class that provides a set of static helper methods or is instantiable class that will be used to create some objects.

I suggest to use the first approach and make the class fully static. In that case you can hide constructor by making it private and protect `LoggerManager` from beeing instantiated with reflection by throwing exception inside that constructor.

```
private LoggerManager() {
    throw new InstantiationException("This is an util class and should not be instantiated.");
}
```

After that I suggest to rethink if `getLogger(String file)` should not be static method. As I can see there is not even a single call to the instance of `LoggerManager`, so you can just add `static` keyword after `public`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to logger which is not instantiated.

In this line `public static Logger logger;` in `LoggerManager.java` you have just created a reference but you have not instantiated. So `logger` is `null`

When you are calling `logger.log`.....

```
 public static void writeLogWarning(Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.toString(), e.fillInStackTrace());
  }
```

as logger is still null so its throwing `NullPointerException`

So before you call log() methods of logger you need to instantiate first

Modify the following line

```
public static Logger logger;
```

to

```
public static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(LoggerManager.class.getName()); ;
```